# MongoDb changes value in embedded doc

Tags: mongodb

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54fd4ddaa037ba481d794f5e"), 
"question" : "let me go?", 
"choices" : [ 
    { 
        "text" : "yes", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("54fd4ddaa037ba481d794f60"), 
        "votes" : [ ] 
    }, { 
        "text" : "y", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("54fd4ddaa037ba481d794f5f"), 
        "votes" : [ ] 
    } 
], 
"__v" : 0 
}
```

I want to change the value "y" to "no", How? 
wish your answer
thanks

Comment: Use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays) operator to set elements in array i.e. `db.collection.update({ _id: ObjectId("54fd4ddaa037ba481d794f5e") }, { $set: { "choices.1.text": "no" }  });`

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays)** operator together with the **[`$ positional`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator in your update to set elements in array without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array i.e.

```
db.collection.update(
    { "question": "let me go?", "choices.text": "y" }, 
    { $set: { "choices.$.text": "no" } }
);
```